# iCloud Documents NSUbiquitousContainers entitlement is not included in the profile

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I can't enable iCloud Documents. I use iCloud key-value storage and CloudKit without problems but when I try to add the following config in the plist:

```
    <key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>iCloud.App</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
            <string>appname</string>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>Any</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I get the following error:

```
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.teamname.appname" doesn't include the NSUbiquitousContainers entitlement
```

Additionally it says:

```
Automatic signing failed. Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at <https://feedbackassistant.apple.com> and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator.
```

Edit:
I also tried to use manual signing then the automatic signing failed error disapears but the entitlement problem still exists.

Comment: Did you add the entitlements within Xcode? Additionally did you add the iCloud container on your App Store Connect side?

Comment: What did you mean with did you add the entitlements, in my question the first code block is the entitlements, isn't? I added the iCloud container through XCode which is also needed for CloudKit and that works fine.

Comment: You also have to add the entitlements within the Developer Portal on Apple. They have to essentially match up so that both sides see the entitlement.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be placed in info.plist and not the entitlements file. Info.plist is moved at new SwiftUI projects to the TARGET settings.